# Embedded youtube fadeout using overlay with asynchronous loader

Tags: javascript, youtube, overlay, fadeout

In [qestion No. 2909178](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909178/jquery-can-you-fadein-a-video) an answer was provided.

The answer included a solution on `jsfiddle`.
The solution/example used HTML with an iframe hardcoded.

I tried to implement this solution but using the youtube asynchronous javascript code instead of a hardcoded iframe. The solution did not work when the asynchronous javascript code is used.

Here is the site where it is not working:

[www.linguashop.com/swahili-to-english](http://www.linguashop.com/swahili-to-english)

The youtube code is here:  [www.linguashop.com/course/java/youtube.js](http://www.linguashop.com/course/java/youtube.js)

The relevant css  is:

```
#player {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 672px;
    height: 378px;
}

#player-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 672px;
    height: 378px;
    background-color: #fff; 
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

The idea is to fadeIn the white overlay in front of the video when it finishes.
This would give the effect of having the videoplayer fade out.

The player is on top of the overlay.
What's need is to have the overlay on top of the player.

Any help would be appreciated.

David

Comment: Please post some code examples and explain what you have already done and where *you* think your problem is. SO is not a place where we write code for you but review *your* code and give tips on how you can improve and fix it.

Comment: Max, I appreciate your comment.  I had assumed the links to the code would be better.  In any case, I found the solution for anyone still looking. The playervars needs this parameter: wmode: 'opaque'.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. Please use the "Answer your own question" button at the bottom to provide the answer.